# Upside-down trees in forest

Tags: forest

I'm trying to typeset a tree which grows upwards using the `forest` package. The problem I have is that as soon as I leave the first level, branches start growing back down again. Here's the code:

```
\begin{forest}{grow=north}
[A [B [a][b]] [C]]
\end{forest}
```

This gives me a tree looking like:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply growing option to the whole tree

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=north}
[A [B [a][b]] [C]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]